# 4 bit multiplier logic gates diagram

Tags: logic-gates, multiplier

I have an assignment that requires building 4-bit Multiplier in two ways:

1) using only FA1bit and AND logic gates.

2) using only FA8bit(Full adder for 8bit numbers) , Mul2bit(Multiplier for numbers with 2 bits)  and AND logic gates .

i figured out the first way , but i cant figure out how to do the second way .

(of course im talking about binary numbers)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to think about how you multiply decimal numbers by hand.

Now, think of your two 4-bit binary numbers as being written in base 4.

Do you see the analogy? Do you see how 2-bit multipliers might apply?

Comment: so let's say i have ABCD , XYWZ are four bit numbers . i can take AB , CD , XY and WZ to be numbers in base 4 since the maximum number can be 11 which is a single digit in base 4 . and then the result would be AB*XY + AB*WZ +CD*XY +CD*WZ ?

Comment: Yes, but with the partial products shifted by appropriate amounts before adding them together.